# Changing background during animation leave artifacts (traces)

Tags: css, css-animations

When I use `transform: scale` and change `background` of the div, I get artifacts (small traces) during the transition. I need to change size and background. It's easier to show than to explain :)

Please check the example here, the last dot https://jsfiddle.net/hades123/29dmx47o/2/

I can use `box-shadow` to hide it, but it's not practical because `background` of the loader can be different.

I'll be grateful if you help me!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `box-shadow` https://jsfiddle.net/hades123/8fmy70ub/1/

It's not so great but it's working fine.